# Build an interactive menu using powershell

Tags: powershell

Below script will display the menu and prompt for a selection.However this doesn't give the option to reselect  if the selection is made wrong.

I would like to re write in such a way that , it should give the option to confirm the selection and if the selection is made wrong, should give an option to re select from the menu. Is it possible using "do until" loop? Any help is high appreciated

```
write-host ""
Write-host -ForegroundColor yellow "Choose which Cluster you want to gather ratios on:"
write-host "(it may take a few seconds to build the list)"
write-host ""

$ICLUSTER = get-cluster -server $VIServer | Select-Object Name | Sort-object Name
if ($null -eq $ICLUSTER)
{
    Update-log "Unable to find Cluster Information.Please verify the cluster status before proceed `n"
    break 
}
else
{
$i = 1
$ICLUSTER | %{Write-Host $i":" $_.Name; $i++}
$HCLUSTER = Read-host "Choose the name of cluster you want to select on by entering corresponding number:"
$SCLUSTER = $ICLUSTER[$HCLUSTER -1].Name
Update-log "You have selected $($SCLUSTER). `n"
start-sleep -s 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A loop & couple additional if statements should get you there:

```
# break the loop by setting $x not equal to 1
$x = 1 

While ($x -eq 1){
$ICLUSTER = get-cluster -server $VIServer | Select-Object Name | Sort-object Name
if ($null -eq $ICLUSTER){
    Update-log "Unable to find Cluster Information. Please verify the cluster status before proceed `n"
    $x = 2
    }
else{
    $i = 1
    $ICLUSTER | %{Write-Host $i":" $_.Name; $i++}
    $HCLUSTER = Read-host "Choose the name of cluster you want to select on by entering corresponding number:"
    $SCLUSTER = $ICLUSTER[$HCLUSTER -1].Name

    if ($SCLUSTER -in $ICLUSTER.Name){
        Write-Host "You have selected $($SCLUSTER), do you want to continue?"
        $yesno = Read-host "Please type 'Y' to continue or 'N' to quit"
        if ($yesno -eq "Y"){
            $x = 1
            }
    else {Write-Host "Quitting"
              $x = 2
              }
    Write-Host "Performing commands"
    # Add commands here, to do the work & complete the task
    $x = 2
    }
elseif (-not($SCLUSTER -in $ICLUSTER.Name)){
    Write-Host "Your selection was not found, Would you like to try again?"
    $yesno = Read-host "Please type 'Y' to try again or 'N' to quit"
    if ($yesno -eq "Y"){
        Write-Host "Trying this again"
        $x = 1
        }
else {Write-Host "Quitting"
      $x = 2
      }
}
start-sleep -s 3
    }
}
```